# How to evaluate that integral accurately and faster?

Tags: numerical-integration

I've the following integral:

$$\int_{-a/2}^{a/2}Cf(x)\sin{\frac{m\pi(x+0.5a)}{a}}\sin{\frac{p\pi(x+0.5a)}{a}}dx$$

where $$f(x) =53.62\cos^4\left(\frac{7\pi\sqrt{x^2}}{9}\right)+3.04\sin^4\left(\frac{7\pi\sqrt{x^2}}{9}\right)+2.54\sin^2\left(\frac{14\pi\sqrt{x^2}}{9}\right)$$

$$m=1,2,\dots,M$$ $$p=1,2,\dots,P$$. $$C=\text{constant}$$

I'm using the following code

```
f[x] = 53.62 Cos[(7 \[Pi] Sqrt[x^2])/9]^4 + 
   3.04 Sin[(7 \[Pi] Sqrt[x^2])/9]^4 + 
   2.54 Sin[(14 \[Pi] Sqrt[x^2])/9]^2;
nL = 20; nC = 20;
K = ConstantArray[0, {nL*nC, nL*nC}];
a=1;b=1;
Do[
  Do[
   Do[
    Do[

     k = (m - 1) nC + n;
     l = (p - 1) nC + q;

     If[n == q, 
      K[[k, l]] = (\[Pi]^2 b m^2 p^2)/(2 a^4)
         NIntegrate[
         f[x] Sin[(m \[Pi] (x + 0.5 a))/a] Sin[(
           p \[Pi] (x + 0.5 a))/a], {x, -a/2, a/2}, 
         Method -> "Trapezoidal"], K[[k, l]] = 0]

     , {q, 1, nC}],
    {p, 1, nL}],
   {n, 1, nC}],
  {m, 1, nL}];
```

Does anyone know another faster and accurate approach?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Did you mean $n\pi$ rather than $p\pi$?

Comment: Hello, @JimB! Oh, I saw, I edited.

Comment: The integral can be calculated symbolically.  First, change $\sqrt{x^2}$ to $x$ three places.  Then change $0.5a$ to $a/2$ two places.  Then do the integral as 3 integrals with different integrands.  Do each integration only once, outside the loops, of course.

Comment: By the way, capital $K$ is a reserved word, so using it as a variable name could cause problems.

Comment: @Nasser, 105s. But I need to perform that 8100 times (there are two external loop)! So, it would be very expensive.

Comment: @LouisB, it's a good approach, but I have two others external loops. So, in each loop $ f (x) $ changes.

Comment: Can you show us the external loops and the different $f(x)$  ?

Comment: @LouisB, really $f(x)$ is only one integral I need to perform. I resume my problem to do not put in a huge code. At long last, bellow it is my code.

Comment: @Nasser, can you show me examples of both options?

Comment: @LouisB, I need to perform similar integrals with D11[x], D12[x], D16[x], D22[x], D26[x] and D66[x] times the sine functions like I put in bellow.

Comment: Notice that your integrals depend on $m$ and $p$, but you recalculate them every time you change $q$.  Also, in the integrals are symmetric in $m$ and $p$, so do not recalculate.  It should be faster if you create a symmetric array of the values of the integrals, then use those matrix elements in q-p-n-m loop.

Comment: It may be interesting to test how long it takes to execute the `Rectangle` and the `ToElementMesh` commands 8281 times.  Can they be taken outside the loops ?

Comment: @LouisB, I did not understand how I would create a summetric array of values. Could you explain to me? Regarding to Rectangle, they can be take outside the loops indeed, I did not notice it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a symmetric array example that will reduce the total integration time.  For simplicity this example is based on the $f(x)$ in your original post.

```
Clear[f, amat, m, p]

f[x] = 53.62 Cos[(7 π Sqrt[x^2])/9]^4 + 
   3.04 Sin[(7 π Sqrt[x^2])/9]^4 + 
   2.54 Sin[(14 π Sqrt[x^2])/9]^2;
nL = 20;

amat = SymmetrizedArray[{m_, p_} :> NIntegrate[f[x] 
      Sin[(m π (x + 0.5 a))/a] Sin[(p π (x + 0.5 a))/a],
    {x, -a/2, a/2},  Method -> "Trapezoidal" ],
  {nL, nL}, Symmetric[{1, 2}]]
```

The code creates a symmetric array `amat`.  The code should be executed before the nested $q-p-n-m-$loop.  Then, inside the nested loop, simply use `amat[ m, p ]` instead of `NIntegrate[ ... ]`.  `amat` must be recalculated only when `f[x]` changes.

We can see the elements of `amat` by evaluating `amat // Normal // MatrixForm`.  We notice that half of the elements are almost zero.

Note that if your `f[x]` is always a linear combination of the same functions every time, and I think it must be, you should find a way to apply `NIntegrate` to those functions outside of all the loops and then calculate linear combinations of the integrals inside the nested loops where the coefficients are known.

Answer (score 2):

For some weird reason that I cannot understand at the moment, this one gets rid of the error messages and is this faster.

```
amat = SymmetrizedArray[{m_, p_} :> Plus[
     NIntegrate[
      f[x] Sin[(m \[Pi] (x + 0.5 a))/a] Sin[(p \[Pi] (x + 0.5 a))/
         a], {x, -a/2, 0}, 
      Method -> {"GaussKronrodRule", "Points" -> 7}],
     NIntegrate[
      f[x] Sin[(m \[Pi] (x + 0.5 a))/a] Sin[(p \[Pi] (x + 0.5 a))/
         a], {x, 0, a/2}, 
      Method -> {"GaussKronrodRule", "Points" -> 7}]
     ], {nL, nL}, Symmetric[{1, 2}]];
```

Should also be much more accurate (no time to check that).

Answer (score 1):

Your integral can be computed in analytic form. No need for numerics. Then you can tabulated it very easy.

Notice that the following definition

```
g[1]=53.62;
g[2]=3.04;
g[3]=2.54;
fp[x_]:=g[1] Cos[(7π)/9 x]^4 + g[2] Sin[(7π)/9 x]^4+ g[3] Sin[(7π)/9 2 x]^2;
```

is equivalent to your function.

I just saw an identical idea in the comments section. All credits to LouisB.

Answer (score 0):

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
G = 6.894745 10^9;
E1 = 26.25 G;
E2 = 1.49 G;
G12 = 1.04 G;
nu12 = 0.28;
nu21 = (E2*nu12)/E1;
t = 0.0050 .0254;
a = 1; b = 1;
u0 = .01;
Son = {{1/E1, -nu12/E1, 0}, {-nu21/E2, 1/E2, 0}, {0, 0, 1/G12}};
Qon = Inverse[Son];

Do[
 Do[
  angles = {{angle0, angle1}, {-angle0, -angle1}, {angle0, 
     angle1}, {-angle0, -angle1}, {angle0, 
     angle1}, {-angle0, -angle1}, {-angle0, -angle1}, {angle0, 
     angle1}, {-angle0, -angle1}, {angle0, 
     angle1}, {-angle0, -angle1}, {angle0, angle1}};

  num = Dimensions[angles][[1]];
  h = num*t;
  pos = Table[0, num + 1];
  pos[[1]] = -h/2;
  For[i = 2, i <= num + 1, i++, pos[[i]] = pos[[i - 1]] + t];
  mA = ConstantArray[0, {3, 3}];
  mB = ConstantArray[0, {3, 3}];
  mD = ConstantArray[0, {3, 3}];

  For[i = 1, i <= num, i++,
   T0 = angles[[i, 1]] ;
   T1 = angles[[i, 2]] ;
   theta[x_] := ((2/a) (T1 - T0) Sqrt[x^2] + T0) (Pi/180);
   m = Cos[theta[x]];
   n = Sin[theta[x]];
   Q11 = Qon[[1, 1]];
   Q12 = Qon[[1, 2]];
   Q22 = Qon[[2, 2]];
   Q66 = Qon[[3, 3]];
   Qxx = m^4*Q11 + n^4*Q22 + 2*m^2*n^2*Q12 + 4*m^2*n^2*Q66;
   Qyy = n^4*Q11 + m^4*Q22 + 2*m^2*n^2*Q12 + 4*m^2*n^2*Q66;
   Qxy = m^2*n^2*Q11 + m^2*n^2*Q22 + (m^4 + n^4)*Q12 + -4*m^2*n^2*Q66;
   Qss = m^2*n^2*Q11 + m^2*n^2*Q22 - 2*m^2*n^2*Q12 + (m^2 - n^2)^2*Q66;
   Qxs = m^3*n*Q11 - m*n^3*Q22 + (m*n^3 - m^3*n)*Q12 + 
     2*(m*n^3 - m^3*n)*Q66;
   Qys = m*n^3*Q11 - m^3*n*Q22 + (m^3*n - m*n^3)*Q12 + 
     2*(m^3*n - m*n^3)*Q66;
   Qoff = {{Qxx, Qxy, Qxs}, {Qxy, Qyy, Qys}, {Qxs, Qys, Qss}};
   mA = mA + Qoff*(pos[[i + 1]] - pos[[i]]);
   mB = mB + Qoff*(pos[[i + 1]]^2 - pos[[i]]^2);
   mD = mD + Qoff*(pos[[i + 1]]^3 - pos[[i]]^3);

   ];

  mB = mB/2;
  mD = mD/3;

  A11[x] = mA[[1, 1]]; A12[x] = mA[[1, 2]]; A16[x] = mA[[1, 3]];
  A22[x] = mA[[2, 2]]; A26[x] = mA[[2, 3]]; A66[x] = mA[[3, 3]];
  D11[x] = mD[[1, 1]]; D12[x] = mD[[1, 2]]; D16[x] = mD[[1, 3]];
  D22[x] = mD[[2, 2]]; D26[x] = mD[[2, 3]]; D66[x] = mD[[3, 3]];

  Nx[x_, y_] = 
   A11[x] D[u[x, y], {x, 1}] + A12[x] D[v[x, y], {y, 1}] + 
    A16[x] (D[u[x, y], {y, 1}] + D[v[x, y], {x, 1}]);

  Ny[x_, y_] = 
   A12[x] D[u[x, y], {x, 1}] + A22[x] D[v[x, y], {y, 1}] + 
    A26[x] (D[u[x, y], {y, 1}] + D[v[x, y], {x, 1}]);

  Nxy[x_, y_] = 
   A16[x] D[u[x, y], {x, 1}] + A26[x] D[v[x, y], {y, 1}] + 
    A66[x] (D[u[x, y], {y, 1}] + D[v[x, y], {x, 1}]);

  PDEs = {
    D[Nx[x, y], {x, 1}] + D[Nxy[x, y], {y, 1}], 
    D[Ny[x, y], {y, 1}] + D[Nxy[x, y], {x, 1}]
    };

  gammaD =
   {
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == -u0/2, x == a/2], 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == u0/2, x == -a/2]
    };

  omega = Rectangle[{-a/2, -b/2}, {a/2, b/2}];

  mesh = ToElementMesh[omega, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001];

  {U, V} =
   NDSolveValue[
    {
     PDEs == {0, 0},
     gammaD,
     DirichletCondition[v[x, y] == 0, y == b/2],
     DirichletCondition[v[x, y] == 0, y == -b/2]
     }
    ,
    {u, v}, {x, y} \[Element] mesh
    ];

  Nx[x_, y_] = 
   A11 D[U[x, y], {x, 1}] + A12 D[V[x, y], {y, 1}] + 
    A16 (D[U[x, y], {y, 1}] + D[V[x, y], {x, 1}]);

  Ny[x_, y_] = 
   A12 D[U[x, y], {x, 1}] + A22 D[V[x, y], {y, 1}] + 
    A26 (D[U[x, y], {y, 1}] + D[V[x, y], {x, 1}]);

  Nxy[x_, y_] = 
   A16 D[U[x, y], {x, 1}] + A26 D[V[x, y], {y, 1}] + 
    A66 (D[U[x, y], {y, 1}] + D[V[x, y], {x, 1}]);

  nL = 20; nC = 20;
  K = ConstantArray[0, {nL*nC, nL*nC}];
  M = ConstantArray[0, {nL*nC, nL*nC}];
  Do[
   Do[
    Do[
     Do[

      k = (m - 1) nC + n;
      l = (p - 1) nC + q;

      If[n == q,
       K[[k, l]] = (\[Pi]^4 b m^2 p^2)/(2 a^4)
           NIntegrate[
           D11[x] Sin[(m \[Pi] (x + 0.5 a))/a] Sin[(
             p \[Pi] (x + 0.5 a))/a], {x, -a/2, a/2}, 
           Method -> "Trapezoidal"]
         + (\[Pi]^4 n^2 q^2)/(2 b^3)
           NIntegrate[
           D22[x] Sin[(m \[Pi] (x + 0.5 a))/a] Sin[(
             p \[Pi] (x + 0.5 a))/a], {x, -a/2, a/2}, 
           Method -> "Trapezoidal"], K[[k, l]] = 0]

      , {q, 1, nC}],
     {p, 1, nL}],
    {n, 1, nC}],
   {m, 1, nL}];
  , {angle0, 0, 90, 1}]
 , {angle1, 0, 90, 1}]
```